# Direct access to iPad Photo library

Tags: ipad

I understand that it's possible to access the iPad Photo library using the UIImagePickerController. The problem with this is that it makes it possible to access only one image at a time. I'm building an app that needs to be able to select multiple images from this library simultaneously (without loading them into memory) to save for further manipulation. This would require obtaining the file paths.

I've read that it's possible to access the Photos file system using the photolibrary.framework. This is a private API though, which would presumably disqualify the app from the App Store.

There are apps in the store that apparently have this capability though. Are they braking Apple's rules or have they found a "legal" way around them?

I've also heard that iOS 4.2 (coming this November) is supposed to make direct access straightforward.

Anyone know of a legal way to access the Photos file system using the current iPad OS?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

There is no API currently available to support that functionality

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project on github: https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

It generally is an ImagePicker that allows to select multiple images at once. Therefore, it needs to read the iOS Photo Library. So looking at the code you should be able to figure out how to do it.